# Remove First Number If It Is A 1

Tags: c#

I have a string that I am removing any nonnumeric values from.  This portion works great, but I can't get my syntax accurate for removing the 1st number if it is a 1.  This is what I have tried, but it presents compile time errors:

```
string num1 = "1abcdedg2345;
string gn = null;
if (num1[0] = "1") { gn = num1.Remove(0, 1); }
else { gn = num1; }  
Console.WriteLine(gn);
```

What do I need to change so that gn will be 2345?  My current syntax always has gn = 12345

Comment: You are trying to do an `assignment`, instead you need a `comparison`. Try if (num1[0] `==` "1"). Note the double ==.

Comment: `num1[0] == "1"` please :)

Comment: `num[0]` returns a `char`, so: `if (num[0] == '1')`

Comment: It would be good to mention what those "compile time errors" were, although I'd imagine that you'd find lots of duplicate questions when searching for those errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are that you are doing an assignment instead of a comparison (`=` vs `==`) and there is a type mismatch between `num1[0]` (`char`) and `"1"` (`string`).  Instead you could use [`string.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) which adds a level of readability.

```
if (num1.StartsWith("1")) { gn = num1.Remove(0, 1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an equals and doing an accidental assignment

```
if (num1[0] == '1') { gn = num1.Remove(0, 1); }
```

edit: also '1' is a char, where "1" is a string (thanks for comment)

Comment: This presents an error of == can not be applied to operands of 'char' and 'string'

Comment: You can use single quotes for char comparison, instead of double quotes. So `'1'` instead of `"1"`.

Comment: It still won't compile since the `num1` string is missing an end quote

Answer (score 1):

in some case (with you example string works) you can do this with a simple

```
string s = "1abcdedg2345";
s = s.TrimStart('1');
// s = "abcdedg2345"
```

pay attention... it will remove all start 1 so it doesn't work with this

```
string s = "1111abcdedg2345";
s = s.TrimStart('1');
// s = "abcdedg2345" it may be correct or not... i don't know...
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "I have a string that I am removing any nonnumeric values from" - Instead you should use a regular expression search/replace to remove anything that isn't a digit

```
string gn = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("df87sdf248f7", @"\D", "");
```

Comment: How does that remove the 1st character if it is a 1?  A 1 is a numeric character

Comment: His goal is "I have a string that I am removing any nonnumeric values from", he is struggling to write code that doesn't ignore the first character. His approach is wrong.